# Bootstrap 3 nesting columns, nested row height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Why nested .row takes height of parent .row?
**Example:**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row"> <!-- Parent .row -->
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>

                <div class="row"> <!-- nested PROBLEMATIC ROW -->
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      Why this row has height of 300px instead of 150px?
                      I can solve problem by setting 'clear: both' on that
                      row, but class .row should do it by itself.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

With some dummy css:

```
.col-md-8 {
    height: 500px;
    background: #f0f0f0;
}
.col-md-6 {
    height: 150px;
    background: red;
}
.col-md-3 {
    height: 150px;
    background: blue;
}
.col-md-12 {
    height: 150px;
    background: yellow;
}
.col-md-4 {
    height: 500px;
    background #f0f0f0;
}
.col-md-4 > div {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 150px;
    background: green;
}
```

Final output: [image]
**JS Bin** : http://jsbin.com/nugoziju/1/edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To begin with, you shouldn't be putting 'col's inside 'col's in Bootstrap without the corresponding row. So your markup looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"> <!-- Parent .row -->
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="row"> <!-- nested PROBLEMATIC ROW -->
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  Why this row has height of 300px instead of 150px?
                  I can solve problem by setting 'clear: both' on that
                  row, but class .row should do it by itself.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And then that's fixed. That row is 150px tall.

Updated jsbin: http://jsbin.com/nugoziju/7

Comment: Indeed that fix the problem.
In official documentation http://getbootstrap.com/css/ in section Nesting columns they dont user additional row

Comment: From what I can see, they use an additional row: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting
The one thing to avoid is putting additional '.container's, which breaks things.